# How to make mouse pointer movement more smooth while remaining fast?

Tags: mouse

I hate moving the mouse too much so I always set its sensitivity to maximum to be able to move the pointer across the whole screen with a humble hand movement.

However the way the pointer responds to the hand movements feels very different in Windows XP (perfectly comfortable), Windows 7 (tolerable) and Ubuntu (pretty itchy).

Does anybody happen to know what is the actual difference between the ways mice behave in these 3 OSes? Are there hidden parameters (I can remember acceleration was a separate slider in older Linux versions for example) I can fine-tune?